# Doctrine ObjectSelect does not remove relation when deselcting

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I have Image and Category entity. Many-To-Many with join table (One-dircetional). I am using Doctirne`s ObjectSelect form element with multiple option. When I select some categories Doctrine succesfully insert the records. But when I want to deselct them - it does not. Am I implemented properly the removeCategories method? May be I am missing something small, but cant figure it out

```
 Class Image
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categories")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="images_categories",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $classBobjects;
    ...
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategories($categories)
    {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $this->categories->add($category);
        }
    }

    public function removeCategories($categories)
    {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $this->categories->remove($category);
        }
    }
```

In form fieldset I have following element

```
 $this->add([
            'name' => 'categories',
            'type' => ObjectSelect::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'multiple' => true,
                'class' => 'chosen-select',
            ],
            'options' => array(
                'object_manager' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get(EntityManager::class),
                'target_class' => Category::class,
                'property' => 'title',
                'is_method' => true,
                'find_method' => array(
                    'name' => 'findAll',
                ),
            ),
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The mistake was in implementing the removeCategories()

```
$this->categories->remove($category);

should be

$this->categories->removeElement($category);
```